# Why is the max-width of the post preview 20px shorter than the real thing?

Tags: feature-request

I make extensive use of imgur's thumbnail feature: appending a special suffix (m) to the image code. The width of the medium thumbnail is 320px, more than half that of the preview (630px) and less than half that of the post (650px). When I have two image codes on the same line, I expect the two medium thumbnails to sit next to each other, but in the preview, the second image gets pushed to the next line. This is rather misleading and a bit of a nuisance because I would expect the preview to look exactly the same as the final output. Is this a bug or expected behavior? What can I do to have the preview width match that of the real thing?

Comment: This created a much bigger issue [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284176/profile-display-gets-cut-off-for-users-with-lots-of-badges)